# How to get top 5 values in bar chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have dataframe named `recent_grads` with columns `Major` and `Unemloyment_rate`. How can I present top 5 Majors with highest unemployment rate in bar chart using matplotlib?

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.bar(recent_grads["Major"][:5],recent_grads["Unemployment_rate"][:5])
plt.show()
```

Comment: It would be better to provide a small example of your data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `.sort_values()` method from pandas to sort by `Unemployment rate` values in a decreasing fashion. Then use `.head()`to print only the 5 first rows:

```
recent_grads.sort_values(by=['Unemployment_rate'], ascending=True).head(5)
```

By the way, 5 is the default number of displayed row using `.head()`, so you don't even need to specify it.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Although the data is unclear, you should sort by "Unemployment_rate", not "Major" (that is probably categorical). Also, better use `nlargest` that does the same as `sort_values`+`head` in one shot and with lesser complexity ;)

Comment: Yes you're right I overlooked this, thanks. Just corrected my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the data is not aggregated, use [`groupby.max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.max.html), then [`nlargest`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html):

```
(recent_grads.groupby('Major')['Unemployment_rate'].max()
 .nlargest(5).plot.bar()
)
```

If the data is already aggregated, only `nlargest`:

```
recent_grads.set_index('Major')['Unemployment_rate'].nlargest(5).plot.bar()
```